# A dedicated NTFS data partition in dual-boot - a better way to communicate data?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hibernate

I know that Ubuntu can access Windows partitions if they are fully shut down, as opposed to only hibernated - if fast boot and hibernation are disabled in Windows.

Right now I can access my data partition, but not the main Windows partition. I thought I had disabled fast boot, but possibly I haven't.

Instead of trying to fix the issue, I have been wondering if it's best to keep things being as they are. Is it better to have this distinction between the OSes, making sure they aren't accessing each other's partitions?

Comment: Entirely up to you. Maybe you might need to access the Windows partition for some reason, maybe not,

Comment: @muru it has happened I need to access files across OSes. I tend to copy regularly to USB sticks or an external hard disk, so I can get them from there too.

Comment: Turns out I have fast start disabled.

Comment: You may need to disable Hibernation in addition to Fast Startup. See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue but i am quite okay not to access the main Windows partition(C: or Windows recovery partition) from Linux. I keep my data which needs to be accessed from Linux in E:(data). Even if Linux is not going to harm anything...i prefer not to touch anything under c:\windows or anything under the Window Recovery partition.
Just my opinion and i don't have facts or reasons to answer your question 100%.